# Automatically set outline and fill color based on GeoJSON properties with geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, geojson, geopandas

I am making a program that retrieves GeoJSON data from past convective outlooks from the Storm Prediction Center (SPC) and plot it using geopandas. With my current code, it is able to plot outlooks correctly onto a map. However, the coloring isn't right. I noticed that the GeoJSON returned by the SPC included outline and fill coloring data for the categories - (in `properties` field)

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": ...}, "properties": {"DN": 2, "VALID": "202109010100", "EXPIRE": "202109011200", "ISSUE": "202109010042", "LABEL": "TSTM", "LABEL2": "General Thunderstorms Risk", "stroke": "#55BB55", "fill": "#C1E9C1"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": ...}, "properties": {"DN": 3, "VALID": "202109010100", "EXPIRE": "202109011200", "ISSUE": "202109010042", "LABEL": "MRGL", "LABEL2": "Marginal Risk", "stroke": "#005500", "fill": "#66A366"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": ...}, "properties": {"DN": 4, "VALID": "202109010100", "EXPIRE": "202109011200", "ISSUE": "202109010042", "LABEL": "SLGT", "LABEL2": "Slight Risk", "stroke": "#DDAA00", "fill": "#FFE066"}}]}
```

Is it possible to use the `stroke` and `fill` data in `properties` to automatically color every `MultiPolygon`?

My current code is below (assume that all packages are imported)

```
outlook = "https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/archive/2021/day1otlk_20210901_0100_cat.lyr.geojson"
world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
)
df = geopandas.read_file(outlook)
ax = world.plot(color='white', edgecolor='#333333',linewidth=0.3)
print(type(df))
s = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df)
s.plot(ax=ax,markersize=0.7,figsize=(1000,1000))
ax.set_xlim(-140, -70) # focus on continental US
ax.set_ylim(25, 50) # focus on continental US
plt.savefig('outlook.jpg', dpi=360) # save as outlook.jpg
```

I tried looking in the geopandas documentation but it didn't state how to use fields in geojson to color polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're one *kwarg* away from the final result. [`plot`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html) accepts [*Series*](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geoseries.html) as an argument for `color` :

> colorstr, np.array, **pd.Series** (def: None) If specified, all objects
> will be colored uniformly.

```
s.plot(ax=ax, color=s["fill"], markersize=0.7, figsize=(1000,1000)) # <-  color=s["fill"] (added here)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to change the opacity of the outlook so that the US borders are still visible?

Comment: Have you tried adding `alpha=1` to adjust its opacity to 100% ?

Comment: I set `alpha=0.7` and it works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: In a similar format I was able to set `edgecolor=s["stroke"]` with working results!

Comment: I tested it and the _map/plot_ now looks even better ;)